# Create menu css/html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I looking for help with my html5 menu with css.
Im trying to create a menu inside only 1 element

This is the code:

```css
#navmax {
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#E78E2E;
}
#navmax ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:white;
}

#navmax ul li {
    text-align: center;
    display:inline;
}
#navmax li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition:0.3s;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height: 35px;
    color:white;
font-family: 'Architects Daughter', cursive;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#navmax li a:hover {
    color:black;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.izq {
    float:left;
}
.der {
    float:right;
}
.mid {
    margin-left:-100px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <nav id="navmax">
    <ul>
    <li><a class="izq" href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a class="izq" href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a class="mid" href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li><a class="der" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
 </body>
  </html>
```

I need to make the "li" PRODUCTS displays a menu with submenus.
1 category of products >>> all the products.

Example (in one singular item)
[Example Products Menu/SubMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qov7i.png)

Thanks you.

Comment: _"I need to make the "li" PRODUCTS displays a menu with submenus. 1 category of products >>> all the products."_ Not sure what Question is? Have you tried including a `<ul>` element having `<li>` elements at `<li>` which has text `"PRODUCTS"`?

Comment: I need to create a menu with the <li> Products </li>. display menu and inside the products shows all the items and that items contain submenus.

Comment: _"I need to create a menu with the <li> Products </li>. display menu and inside the products shows all the items and that items contain submenus."_ Yes, provided suggestion which should render expected display of menu items at previous comment. What have you tried to solve Question?

Comment: @guest271314 I tried with other codes from stackoverflow but it's a mess. Editing CSS and showing errors randomly. Who can I do it? you saw the pic? https://i.stack.imgur.com/qov7i.png ty

Comment: Yes, viewed the image; though note, images usually do not describe the issue accurately. Text at actual Question  tends to describe details more thoroughly.

Comment: @guest271314 Im confused with ul li ul li items haha. you can check the css / html inside the post and try to teach me how to do it? I try with another codes but like you see, the "products" its the only one I need centered and with menu.

Comment: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-menu-with-submenu-using-css-html/26146

Comment: @pol I will try it.

Comment: @jukxz Should second menu always be displayed?

Comment: @guest271314 when you "hover" with the mouse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to include a subsidiary unordered list inside the list item:

```css
#navmax {
    width: 560px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#navmax ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:white;
}

#navmax ul li {
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color:#E78E2E;
}
#navmax li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition:0.3s;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height: 35px;
    color:white;
font-family: 'Architects Daughter', cursive;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#navmax li a:hover {
    color:black;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#navmax li ul {
display: none;
width: 140px;
margin: auto;
}

#navmax li:hover ul {
display: block;
}

#navmax li:hover ul li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <nav id="navmax">
    <ul>
    <li><a class="izq" href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a class="izq" href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a class="mid" href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="der" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: nice one, but I think now its time to add a sub-menu in  the product list. I thing with left:100% or something like that. its possible?

Comment: @jukxz You cannot expect users to fine-tune the implementation for you. Especially where no actual Question or effort to solve own issue is presented at OP. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry for that. I will adjust for my self. I just asking because I tried and failed. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I have every confidence you can take it from here, @jukxz - my intention was to signpost the way forward for you.

Comment: @Rounin thanks for that. I tried with another codes but failed with the positions, displays and I confuse with something wrong code. I will try.